# Same font size in a fixed width/height Div is displayed differently in two PCs.

Tags: javascript, html, css

When viewing a webapp that has fixed (height/width) div with fixed content is displaying very differently (ie:bigger fonts,line break) in different PCs .

*The JS pixel depth is same in both the PCs.*

[Screenshot : The webapp in PC-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKIWD.jpg)

[Screenshot : The webapp in PC-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWzn1.png)

In the first PC - the content appeared in a single line
In the second PC - the content appeared in two lines (Compare it with first PC)

**Tried with same resolution - but still the content appears different .**

Is this because the CSS pixel and device pixel is different ?

If there is any way to make the content appear same on all the PC displays  , Please answer here .(***Without changing the font size and zoom property***)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a set of css reset rules. User can set default fonts and size in browser and are probably different in each one shown

Comment: The font is different. Your PCs doesn't have the same fonts available. Different fonts have looks and sizes. You might need to use a web font to make sure it is available and used in both computers

Comment: @RomanCortes Thanks , it worked .

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/). Unstyled Websites look different on every OS since there are various default fonts and OS-specific Styles, such as `line-height`s and `font-size`s.

As for the font, just embed some fonts in your project. If you do not specify a font, Windows will fall back to Times New Roman for example.

Comment: the main thing is that he using 2 diff. OS not PC's , good suggestion

Comment: Yeah . I am using web font now, It is working perfectly .

Answer (score 0):

I don not know if you uploaded your font file.
But here is a way to get your font in css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: main-font;
  src: url(nameOfFontFile.ttf);
}
```

Use the name `main-font` by font in your css file.

```
#someId {
  font-family: main-font;
}
```